# Как использовать 1 коммит в другом репозитории?

Tags: java, android, git

Есть ли возможность в Android studio использовапть 1 коммит 1 репозитория в другом.

Суть в том что я в 1 и в 2 репозитории одинаковые файлы.

В 1 репозитории я удалил порядка 5 мегабайт файлов. И чтобы все это вручную не делать в 2 репозитории в том числе и в 3. То есть ли возможность использовать этот коммит во 2 репозитории. Как бы автоматизировать процесс?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Да, можно. Но только студия тут ни при чем (хотя, думаю, можно изголиться и через нее все сделать).

Первое, что нужно сделать - это снять "дамп изменений" - патч. Для этого, открываем терминал, заходим в папку с проектом, с помощью git log смотрим историю и находим нужный коммит. Дальше, зная коммит, сохраняем патч. Это будет где то так

```
git show <sha-хеш> -p > <файл-с-патчем.patch>
```

или так

```
git format-patch -1 <sha-хеш> --stdout > <файл-с-патчем.patch>
```

полученный файл переносим к новому репозиторию, заходим в папку к нему и делаем

```
git apply <файл-с-патчем.patch>
```

Если все происходит на одной машине, то файл патча не обязательно копировать.

При применении патча могут быть конфликты. И их нужно будет решить.

Comment: Насчет конфликтов. Может посоветуете какую нибудь программу тогда чтобы онеа конфликты показывалаа?

Или после патчинга в новом репозитории. Открыв Android Studio я получу окно конфликтов?

Comment: git status сообщит о  том, что если конфликты. А потом отрываем любым редактором файлы (или весь проект) и ищем строки вида "=======" или "<<<<<<<" (по 7 штук) - это и будут места конфликтов.